# User that does not use password to login needs it to run a command

Tags: password, auto-login

The user is set to login without a password.  When trying to use that user to make a directory the user is asked to prvide a password.  Since they don't have a password the system keeps rejecting them and denies them access to the command.  Is there a default password that may be in use?

Comment: Please describe the steps you're taking that gives you the password prompt.

Answer (score 3):

That the user can log in without providing a password, does not mean that the user does not *have* a password. It only means that the system does not require it, to let them in.

The answer to your last question is: No, there is no default password.

If you have another user on the same system, who knows their password and has `sudo` permissions, then they can change the password for the user who forgot theirs. Otherwise, you should proceed with a password recovery procedure, one of which is described in this post: [Psychocats - How to reset your password in Ubuntu](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword/).

There is also mention of recovery by dropping to single user mode in the [Ubuntu Community Documentation - Lost Password](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword)